# TIAGo Installation-Dependencies Issue

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with ROS melodic

- ros-melodic-desktop-full is already the newest version (1.4.1-0bionic.20200130.024635
- ros-melodic-ros-core is already the newest version (1.4.1-0bionic.20191211.035951)

I followed tutorials to install TIAGo,
When I ran this command

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic --skip-keys="opencv2 opencv2-nonfree pal_laser_filters speed_limit_node sensor_to_cloud hokuyo_node libdw-dev python-graphitesend-pip python-statsd pal_filters pal_vo_server pal_usb_utils pal_pcl pal_pcl_points_throttle_and_filter pal_karto pal_local_joint_control camera_calibration_files pal_startup_msgs pal-orbbec-openni2 dummy_actuators_manager pal_local_planner gravity_compensation_controller current_limit_controller dynamic_footprint dynamixel_cpp tf_lookup opencv3"
```

I got this error

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
pal_navigation_cfg_ari: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [polycost_layer]
```

Ps. git repo of pal_naviation_cfg_ari is below

https://github.com/pal-robotics/pal_navigation_cfg_public/tree/master/pal_navigation_cfg_ari

Updated : Problem solved with reinstall Ubuntu and all the things work like charms!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344261/tiago-installation-dependencies-issue/) by [Reaper151](https://answers.ros.org/users/51806/reaper151/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2020-02-16**:
This `polycost_layer` dependency should be added to the `--skip-keys` list, once you do it, it should work out of the box.

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic --skip-keys="opencv2 opencv2-nonfree pal_laser_filters speed_limit_node sensor_to_cloud hokuyo_node libdw-dev python-graphitesend-pip python-statsd pal_filters pal_vo_server pal_usb_utils pal_pcl pal_pcl_points_throttle_and_filter pal_karto pal_local_joint_control camera_calibration_files pal_startup_msgs pal-orbbec-openni2 dummy_actuators_manager pal_local_planner gravity_compensation_controller current_limit_controller dynamic_footprint dynamixel_cpp tf_lookup opencv3 polycost_layer"
```

**Comment by [Reaper151](https://answers.ros.org/users/51806/reaper151/) on 2020-02-16**:
I use your command but result is

> 

*pal_navigation_cfg_ari: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [visited_recovery]*

> 

then, I add it to --skip-keys list but then the error change to

> 

*ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-teb-local-planner] failed*

> 

then, I ran the command below

> 

*sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-teb-local-planner*

> 

and the result is

> 

*E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-teb-local-planner*

> 

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2020-02-16**:
Ok, then try to simply remove the `pal_naviation_cfg_ari` package and clean your workspace and do it again. It should work.

**Comment by [Reaper151](https://answers.ros.org/users/51806/reaper151/) on 2020-02-16**:
Could you tell me what command to clean workspace?

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2020-02-16**:
You are having the issue at the `rosdep install` stage, so try running the command again. and see whats the issue. Make sure that you run `apt-get update` before

**Comment by [Reaper151](https://answers.ros.org/users/51806/reaper151/) on 2020-02-16**:
I delete `pal_navigation_cfg_ari` folder and I also ran `apt list --installed` and didn't see `ros-melodic-pal_navigation_cfg_ari`.

I ran `sudo apt-get update`  then `rosdep install` and get this

> ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-teb-local-planner] failed

**Comment by [roshc2](https://answers.ros.org/users/51814/roshc2/) on 2020-02-16**:
I'm having the exact same error. It would be very helpful if someone knows how to solve it.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2020-04-06**:
@roshc2 which error do you have?

**Comment by [roshc2](https://answers.ros.org/users/51814/roshc2/) on 2020-04-06**:
@Procópio I'm not getting the error anymore. It was the same issue described by Reaper151. After a couple days, I reinstalled everything (including Linux) and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue has been fixed upstream, just need to update your repo, and clean it.

This is a bug. Please create an issue in the repository https://github.com/pal-robotics/pal_navigation_cfg_public/tree/master/pal_navigation_cfg_ari

While the bug is not fixed, as mentioned by @saikishor, you can have a workaround by editing this file:
https://github.com/pal-robotics/pal_navigation_cfg_public/blob/master/pal_navigation_cfg_ari/package.xml

remove the lines 24 and 26:

```
  <exec_depend>visited_recovery</exec_depend>

  <exec_depend>polycost_layer</exec_depend>
```

then do a `catkin clean -b` to clean your workspace and then run the `rosdep` command again.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2020-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reaper151](https://answers.ros.org/users/51806/reaper151/) on 2020-02-17**:\

1. I did your procedure
2. I got this

> *ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
> apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-teb-local-planner] failed*
> 3. I clone [link text](https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner)
> 4. I got this
> *ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
> apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-robot-localization] failed*
> 5. I clone [link text](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization)
> 6. I got
> *ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
> apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-urdf-test] failed*
> 7. BUT this time I don\t know which repo should I clone

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2020-02-17**:
The errors that you are having now are related to installing debian packages that should exist. You do not need to clone each of this repos, as they are released under ROS.
Did you correctly set up your ROS repositories?
Did you do a `sudo apt-get update` before running the `rosdep` command?

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2020-02-17**:
@Reaper151 run this command `apt-cache search ros-melodic-robot-localization` and let us know what you see (or) `apt-cache search melodic` and see if you can see other melodic packages.
Better run `apt-get update` before running the above commands

**Comment by [Reaper151](https://answers.ros.org/users/51806/reaper151/) on 2020-02-17**:
@Procópio yes

**Comment by [Reaper151](https://answers.ros.org/users/51806/reaper151/) on 2020-02-17**:
@saikishor

### apt-cache search ros-melodic-robot-localization
Ignoring file 'realsense-public.list ' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

apt-cache search melodic

solfege
tinyeartrainer
ros-melodic-kdl-parser-py
ros-melodic-visualization-marker-tutorials
ros-melodic-rqt-logger-level
ros-melodic-warehouse-ros
ros-melodic-cpp-common
ros-melodic-navfn
ros-melodic-moveit-commander
ros-melodic-rqt-topic
ros-melodic-sound-play
ros-melodic-roscpp-tutorials
ros-melodic-moveit-ros-manipulation
ros-melodic-forward-command-controller
ros-melodic-rosconsole-bridge
ros-melodic-visualization-msgs
ros-melodic-gazebo-ros
ros-melodic-teleop-tools-msgs
ros-melodic-geometry-msgs
ros-melodic-rqt-srv
ros-melodic-rostest
ros-melodic-twist-mux
ros-melodic-catkin
ros-melodic-rqt-shell
...and so on

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2020-02-17**:
@Reaper151 It seems the problem is not with the TIAGo simulation packages, it has something to do with your ROS setup, try to do the same using a ROS Melodic Docker and check what's happening (or) try to reinstall your ROS and check again.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2020-02-17**:
@Reaper151, as @saikishor mentioned, it seems there is something wrong with your repositories configuration. The packages that you cannot install do exist (check here: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/).

What happens if you execute the following?
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-teb-local-planner ros-melodic-urdf-test ros-melodic-robot-localization`

Nevertheless, I'd suggest you to open a new question, as this problem is unrelated with the original issue you were encountering.

**Comment by [Reaper151](https://answers.ros.org/users/51806/reaper151/) on 2020-02-17**:
@Procópio I ran your command and got ten some warning about "Target ... is configured  multiple times" and 3 error "unable to locate package ros-melodic-teb-local-planner / ros-melodic-urdf-test / ros-melodic-robot-localization"

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2020-02-17**:
@Reaper151 the problem you are facing now is related to your repositories configuration. These are default ROS packages that should be installed without any hassle. Review your configs in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` .
As I said, this is getting out of the scope of the original question. I suggest you open a new one regarding this specific issue.
You can also google the error "Target ... is configured multiple times", and you'll get a better idea of the problem

**Comment by [Reaper151](https://answers.ros.org/users/51806/reaper151/) on 2020-02-18**:
Could you advice me how to link back to this question?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2020-02-18**:
yes, just copy the page url and paste it in the other question.